# How create button for stored file in server in Odoo v8?

Tags: python, odoo-8

I try to develop a button in **Odoo v8.0**. This button is for download a stored specific file in a folder of a server. When user try to click the button then the function returns a new tab with a stored specific **PDF** document (Not generated report) in a browser of a client.

View code:

```
<button name="download_doc_one"  type="object" string="Download PDF 1" help="Solicite el documento."/>
```

Python code:

```
@api.multi
def download_doc_one(self):
    url = "http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html" #example url
    return webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

Result: not error but not response.

Answer (score 0):

The `webbrowser` approach will attempt to open the `url` in a browser on the server. Assuming you would like to open the `url` in the user's browser, you can do the following:

```
@api.multi
def download_doc_one(self):
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'url': 'http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html' #example url
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

Users might need to allow pop-ups for your Odoo website.